# sending activation emails-Django

Tags: django, email, django-models, django-views

I am creating an inactive user and want to send them email for activating there accounts like the one django-registration send when we create an account.

This is my views.py

```
user = User.objects.create_user(userName, userMail,userPass)
 user.is_active=False
 user.save()
```

Comment: If you do not want to use django-registration, you'll just have to look at its code and reproduce the mechanism it implements. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i want to send the mail like django-registration but i dont know how to send when i am creating user myself

Answer (score 1):

You should review the topical guide on [sending emails](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/). Basically, you'll just use the components from `django.core.mail` to send an activation email with all the necessary information after you've created the user instance.

It's important that that email contains further information on how the user is supposed to activate their account. The way `django-registration` does it is that it has a separate model associated with the `User` instance that specified a unique identifier which would be used in the activation view to identify which user account is supposed to be activated, i.e. creating a `GET` request to `http://foo/accounts/activate/550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000` would activate the user account with the associated UUID.

There are some other intricate details that make `django-registration` a thorough and well-polished solution, in spite of being a bit dated (i.e. no class-based views), so I second @NCao in suggesting that you take enough time to review the sources from the [official repository](https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration) and ripoff and duplicate all the necessary bits.

Answer (score 0):

Basically after a user signed up, you want to set user.is_active=False.

Then you send an URL with the user's information(for example, id) to the user's email.

When the user click the link, it will trigger an activation function. Within the activation function, it firstly extracts the user's information based on the URL (id). Then you can query the user object by calling user.objects.get(id=id). After that, you can set user.is_active=True and save user.

Here is the code to send email:
        from email.mime.text import MIMEText
        from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

```
    fromaddr='your email address' #(Gmail here)
    username='your user name'
    password='your password'
    def send_email(toaddr,id):
        text = "Hi!\nHow are you?\nHere is the link to activate your
        account:\nhttp://127.0.0.1:8000/register_activate/activation/?id=%s" %(id)
        part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg.attach(part1)
        subject="Activate your account "
        msg="""\From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s""" % (fromaddr,toaddr,subject,msg.as_string())
        #Use gmail's smtp server to send email. However, you need to turn on the setting "lesssecureapps" following this link:
        #https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(username,password)
        server.sendmail(fromaddr,[toaddr],msg)
        server.quit()
```

You may also want to check this out: https://github.com/JunyiJ/django-register-activate
Hope it helps!